# googleapis people list, difference between visible and connected

Tags: google-plus

I am testing a google+ api. I am confusing about a parameter in the plus.people.list api. Google+ API v1 see [Google+ API v1](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list), this interface need a collection parameter with value connected or visible.

I want to know how I can reappear the situation when a google+ account is or is not in the another google+ account's connected plus.people.list.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the documentation [People: list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list).  Connected refers to if they both use your application.

> Acceptable values are:
>   •"connected": The list of visible people in
>   the authenticated user's circles who also use the requesting app. This
>   list is limited to users who made their app activities visible to the
>   authenticated user.
>   •"visible": The list of people who this user has
>   added to one or more circles, limited to the circles visible to the
>   requesting application.

Comment: I thought it so, to show users use the same app. But a wierd situation is I applied two google+ accouts(say A,B), and I used them in my same app. Then I requested the plus.people.list api, with the result that there was account B in the "connected" return of account A while there was no account A in the "connected" return of account B. If connected refers to the "both", should the both api returns the connected each other?

Comment: Do both A and B have each other in circles? are both set public? something is different between the two accounts I would bet.